# Getting length of toggle classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

This might be similar to getting length of a class. But I am not getting the actual output for toggle class.

So here is the scenario: I have a table in which there is a checkbox in every row. If check all option is selected, all checkbox is marked. Now the problem is that I want to pass flag as true when all checkbox are checked and false when only some checkboxes are checked. Now I use toggling functionality. So I don't know how I get length of 'unchecked' checkboxes rather than 'unchecked checked' checkboxes.(I am using Div's for styling instead of checkboxes. )

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yp56c/)

Script for counting length:

```
$("#cntCheck").click(function(){
    alert($('.isChecked').length);      //Counting Checked CheckBox(Working right).
});

$("#cntUncheck").click(function(){
    alert($('.checkBox isChecked').length); //Counting Unchecked CheckBox Except CheckAll checkbox(This is not working)
});
```

Comment: You have no checkboxes in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: You are missing `.` for the class selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your (very confusing) question correctly, you're asking how to count the elements that *do* have the `checkBox` class but *don't* have the *isChecked* class. If so, you can use the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$(".checkBox").not(".isChecked").length
```

Or, the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(".checkBox:not(.isChecked)").length
```

Regarding your styling:

> *"I am using Div's for styling instead of checkboxes."*

I would strongly recommend *against* doing this, because users who don't like to (or are physically unable to) use a mouse or other pointing device can't click your pseudo-checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks your code is working. And thank you so much for your suggestion. I'll modify my code. Your 1st code is working. Here is the solved jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp56c/2/

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Yp56c/3/

```
$("#cntUncheck").click(function(){
    var notChecked = $('.checkBox').not('.isChecked').length;
    alert(notChecked); //This is working
});
```